Can I run a python static binary without root privilege in a docker container?
I have the following Dockerfile:
FROM cgr.dev/chainguard/wolfi-base as builder

ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

COPY . /code/app

RUN apk add --no-cache python-3.11 git wget jq build-base posix-libc-utils \
  && python3 -m venv /venv

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN wget $(wget -qO- https://api.github.com/repos/NixOS/patchelf/releases/latest | jq -r '.assets[] | select(.name | contains("aarch64")) | .browser_download_url') -O patchelf.tar.gz \
    && tar -xvf patchelf.tar.gz && install ./bin/patchelf /usr/bin/patchelf
    
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir pyinstaller staticx \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /code/app/requirements-ci.txt \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir /code/app

WORKDIR /code/app

RUN pyinstaller static.spec && staticx dist/main dist/main_app

FROM cgr.dev/chainguard/static:latest-glibc

COPY --from=builder /code/app/dist/main_app /main_app

# this runs as user nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/main_app"]

I start with the installation of python in the builder, together with some tools that will be necessary to build the static version of my python app with pyinstaller and staticx. The last stage publishes the application in the chainguard/static image, which amounts to more or less the same as a FROM scratch (with some basic advantages, like a proper user management, time zones, certificates, etc.).
When I run it in docker image cgr.dev/chainguard/wolfi-base, where the default user is root, the binary produced by staticx works flawlessly. The application runs as expected.
When I run it as above, in docker image cgr.dev/chainguard/static:latest-glibc, it turns out the user is nonroot, which is great, but then I get the following error:
Failed to open /proc/self/exe: Permission denied

That's because nonroot is not provided access to /proc/self/exe.
I want to produce a static binary out of my python application that I can run as nonroot. I believe the way I told above is kind of standard, but unfortunately makes it impossible. Is there another way?

What are the permissions on /main_app?

Using pyinstaller inside Docker seems weird - Docker lets you ship a Python interpreter as part of the Docker image, without requiring the end-user to install Python. pyinstaller can work without a Python interpreter, but at the cost that it essentially bundles a Python interpreter as part of the executable. It seems like using pyinstaller is unnecessary here.

I'm not sure of the relevance of using pyinstaller in a docker image, honestly. My aim is to reduce the attack surface as much as possible in the container. If a potential hacker is able to enter into this container and gets access to a python interpreter, I guess things can go bad, even though there are ways to set limits. I am unsure access to an interpreter is really avoided with my way of producing the application image.
The perms on /main_app are root, I will try to change that.

If a potential hacker is able to enter into the container, they'll also be able to trivially use the Docker daemon to compromise the entire host.  It's sounding like you might want a compiled language and not necessarily Python.

because nonroot is not provided access to /proc/self/exe that is odd, your user has no access to /main_app. Just add read permissions to /main_app.

@DavidMaze with the right AppArmor / SELinux profile and the right security context, I don't think what you say is possible, though we should always be careful when we say impossible in the context of hacking

Has anyone an idea how a vulnerability scanner can find vulnerabilities (in the python packages / dependencies) now everything is statically bound as a single executable?

After the useful comments that I got on my post, I am able to finally make it work with the following dockerfile:
FROM cgr.dev/chainguard/wolfi-base as builder

ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

COPY . /code/app

RUN apk add --no-cache python-3.11 git wget jq build-base posix-libc-utils \
  && python3 -m venv /venv

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN wget $(wget -qO- https://api.github.com/repos/NixOS/patchelf/releases/latest | jq -r '.assets[] | select(.name | contains("aarch64")) | .browser_download_url') -O patchelf.tar.gz \
    && tar -xvf patchelf.tar.gz && install ./bin/patchelf /usr/bin/patchelf
    
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir pyinstaller staticx \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /code/app/requirements-ci.txt \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir /code/app

WORKDIR /code/app

RUN pyinstaller static.spec && staticx dist/main dist/main_app

FROM cgr.dev/chainguard/static:latest-glibc

COPY --chown=nonroot --from=builder /code/app/dist/main_app /main_app

# this runs as user nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/main_app"]

Note the additional chown nonroot:nonroot dist/main_app at the end of the builder stage. It's all fine, it works.

It works, but if your goal is hardening, +r permissions make sense but chown does not. (I also share the concerns in comments about whether pyinstaller actually does anything useful; it's still bundling a Python interpreter and standard library into your container, and any attacker who can run arbitrary Python code will be able to unbundle them. Single binary containers are good hardening practice, but pyinstaller mostly just fakes it; in many modes it's unpacking into separate files in tmpfs during runtime).

The other thing is that the extra unpacking pyinstaller does prevents the files that would otherwise be shared between containers and able to share block cache entries on the host are being independently unpacked and stored. You're getting little security benefit (couldn't say "none" without threat model review), but paying in both memory and startup performance.
